# PFQueryTableViewController Parse. Not loading image

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery

Hi I am trying the code bellow and I can't get my image showing

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

     PFTableViewCell *cell = (PFTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[PFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     }

     // Configure the cell
     cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"venueName"];
     cell.imageView.file = [object objectForKey:@"image"];
    [cell.imageView.file getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error){
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    }];

     return cell;
 }
```

I also try:

```
[cell.imageView loadInBackground];
```

and nothing. Do I need to insert manually an UIImage in the cell?

Regards

Comment: The first I think you should fix your format post. About your question, are you sure [object objctForKey:@"image"] return PFFile?

Comment: Sorry about the format. Yes the files are being downloaded. I am printing them using NSLog

Comment: Don't do the `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:` part. The `image` property is a placeholder in case the remote image is unavailable.

Comment: I tried loadInBackground and it didn't work either. I try not to implement the cellForRowAtIndexPath and it works. However, I want to implements my custom cell. Another thing that I notice is that the images are the same until the scroll stops, probably because of the reusable cell. The results is terrible. I want something similar to facebook or instagram

Comment: I think you should try to custom a Cell(normal cell), with PFImageView and UILabel and use loadInbackground to load PFImageView. Another thing, i set a placeholder image, when you scroll, your tableview show the image, and after scroll it load image from Parse.

Comment: But if you put a placeholder, even after you retrieve from parse and continue scrolling the image will be replaced by the placeholder again. Thats not very good.

Answer (score 0):

To load a image from Parse.com (using PFImageView), you just do it:

```
   creature.file = (PFFile *)file;
   [creature loadInBackground];
```

Comment: If I dont implement cellForRowAtIndePath. It works just fine; however I want to customise my cell.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the property "image" is a file? If it is, try this:

```
PFFile *theImage = [object objectForKey:@"image"];
[theImage getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error){
    NSData *imageFile = [theImage getData];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageFile];
}];
```